# Is there a GUI available to upload files like "kubectl cp" does?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Asking for a friend. ;)

Is there a Graphical User Interface available to upload something to a pod, like `kubectl cp` does?

I am either thinking of a desktop application like WinSCP, Filezilla or Cyberduck,

or a very simple webapp, i.e. deployed as a pod. I'd then mount the volume to a path and the user may upload files via the simple web interface.

Answer (score 0):

I severely doubt it. `kubectl cp` is actually more or less just an alias for `kubectl exec -t tar ...` and then it pipes in a tarball datastream. It's not even on the same level as SCP, let alone more "real" file transfer protocols. It's mostly intended for debugging and not anything serious. Real file management should probably happen via persistent volumes of some kind, probably whatever hosted NFS product your cloud offers.

Comment: You are totally right, but maybe there is some "visual Kubernetes management" solution that also supports uploading. Problem is, people who are not capable of using `kubectl cp` are also not able to handle ssh keys... As I said, asking for a friend ;).

Comment: I can't say for sure but again, I very very much doubt anyone has bothered.

Comment: Perhaps you misunderstand what Kubernetes is for? It is not equivalent to a VPS or VM hosting system.